# Посчитать количество пятниц между двумя датами

Tags: javascript

Нужно рассчитать сколько пятниц осталось до дня рождения, у меня пока получилось, только сколько дней просчитать...подскажите как исправить?

```
<html>
<script language=javascript>
a=24;
b=6;
c=2013;
today=new Date(c,b,a);
var d=prompt("Введите дату:"," ");
var e=prompt("Введите месяц (0-январь...11-декабрь):"," ");
var f=prompt("Введите год:"," ");
var start=new Date(f,e,d);
document.write("До дня рождения осталось (пятниц):" + Math.round(Math.ceil((today.getTime()-start.getTime())/(1000*60*60*24*7)))); 
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Я бы предложил следующую идею:

1. Находите какую-нибудь субботу, например, в прошлом. Назовём её «день X».
2. Для данной даты считаете расстояние от неё до дня Х в днях. Частное от целочисленного деления этого расстояния на 7 есть количество пятниц, прошедших между днём Х и данной датой. (Убедитесь, что округление идёт вниз. Для этого в принципе достаточно выбрать день Х достаточно далеко в прошлом, чтобы данная дата была *после* дня Х.)
3. То же считаете для дня рождения.
4. Вычитая полученное в пунктах 2 и 3, получите искомое.

Comment: Всё это конечно замечательно, но как это написать? =D

Comment: @Лана а как вы написали код из примера ?

Comment: @Лана: А какой из пунктов вызывает затруднения?

Comment: Эмм, количество дней поделить на 7? И пару проверок добавить.

Comment: @lampa: Ну, не совсем. Например, с понедельника по среду у нас 0 пятниц, а вот с четверга по субботу уже одна. Вот эта самая «пара проверок» сложнее концептуально, чем поделить два раза на 7 и вычесть.

Answer (score 2):

Вроде считает правильно(редко с этим языком работаю). Выполняется медленно, зато точно. А javascript такие вещи меньше чем за секунду обрабатывает.

```
var d = 22;
var e = 5;
var f = 2013;

/*
var d=prompt("Введите дату:"," ");
var e=prompt("Введите месяц (0-январь...11-декабрь):"," ");
var f=prompt("Введите год:"," ");
*/
день_рождения=new Date(f,e,d);

var d = 20;
var e = 5;
var f = 2013;
var дата_отсчёта = new Date(f,e,d);

var всего_пятниц = 0;

if(день_рождения.valueOf() > дата_отсчёта.valueOf())
{
do
{
if(дата_отсчёта.getDay() == 5) // если пятница увеличиваем счётчик
{
всего_пятниц++;
}

дата_отсчёта.setDate(дата_отсчёта.getDate() + 1); // прибавляем по 1 дню
}while(день_рождения.valueOf() > дата_отсчёта.valueOf());
}

document.write("До дня рождения осталось (пятниц):" + всего_пятниц);
```

Comment: Хм, надо ещё проверить случай, когда введённая дата _после_ дня рожденья.

Comment: Не очень понимаю. Ведь если дата после, то должно возвращаться 0. То есть уже прошло. Иначе год дня рождения увеличить на 1.

Или вы про другое?

Comment: @manking: Я почему-то думал, что цикл при этом не закончится. Вечер, мозги надо отправлять на отдых :-)

Но всё же кажется один крайний случай есть: если день рожденья — четверг, и дата отсчёта **совпадает** с днём рожденья, результат будет 1, а не 0. Правда, этот крайний случай не для случая сегодняшней даты отсчёта, т.к. сегодня не четверг.

Comment: поморочено, зачем тут вообще циклы ? все же периоды стабильны, дни недели и дни. вот если бы "сколько пятниц 13го до даты" то да, это было бы сложнее.

Comment: @VladD 
Да для четверга вернул 1. Сейчас поставил проверку перед циклом. А здесь сам день рождения считается?

Comment: С пятницами 13-го тоже можно обойтись _частично_ без циклов, т. к. количество дней в 400 годах делится на 7.

Comment: @manking: это к автору вопроса, я точно не знаю.

Comment: Всем огромное спасибо за помощь)